# Find Certain String Indices

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have this string and I need to get a specific number out of it.

E.G. `encrypted = "10134585588147, 3847183463814, 18517461398"`

How would I pull out only the second integer out of the string?

Comment: What do you mean by second index? The second word?

Comment: By index I mean when it get separated by the commas

Comment: So to clarify, that'd be `3847183463814` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the "split" method. Turn a string into a list by specifying a smaller part of the string on which to split.

```
>>> encrypted = '10134585588147, 3847183463814, 18517461398'
>>> encrypted_list = encrypted.split(', ')
>>> encrypted_list
['10134585588147', '3847183463814', '18517461398']
>>> encrypted_list[1]
'3847183463814'
>>> encrypted_list[-1]
'18517461398'
```

Then you can just access the indices as normal. Note that lists can be indexed forwards or backwards. By providing a negative index, we count from the right rather than the left, selecting the last index (without any idea how big the list is). Note this will produce `IndexError` if the list is empty, though. If you use Jon's method (below), there will always be at least one index in the list unless the string you start with is itself empty.

Edited to add:

What Jon is pointing out in the comment is that if you are not sure if the string will be well-formatted (e.g., always separated by **exactly one comma followed by exactly one space**), then you can replace all the commas with spaces (`encrypt.replace(',', ' ')`), then call split without arguments, which will split on any number of whitespace characters. As usual, you can chain these together:

```
encrypted.replace(',', ' ').split()
```

Comment: How would that work if I wanted to find the last index without opening encrypted. I need to do this without knowing how many indexes there are. After finding the indexes, I want so subtract without knowing the index so is there a loop that can be used.

Comment: Sure, if you're not positive the string is well-behaved, as the one in the example is. Added a section.

Comment: @JaiminN Added to the answer. Just use negative indices.